# Custom error message for input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to set a custom message for an input:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'Choose a business, Mang!');
```

and display this:

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
```

But nothing displays for me, what is wrong?

Is this what I need? Example:

```
if($result)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'Choose a business, Mang!');
}
```

Comment: show your complete code please of your validation

Comment: Have you set up a validation rule called username?

Comment: I need this `if($result){$this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'Corect!');}`

Comment: @user2287965 what you just said makes no sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set rules as such:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field_username', 'username', 'required|callback_business_check');

function business_check($username) {
    if(strlen($this->input->post('form_field_business')) == 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('business_check', 'Choose a business, Mang!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is providing I have the right idea of what you are doing...

Comment: Maybe is passible `if $result == true` then set error message `for_form_field_name` ?

Comment: `if ($result == true) { $this->form_validation->set_message('business_check', 'Choose a business, Mang!'); }`I can't use function, I need check is same function